# Communicate between two applications web

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, adfs

I have two web applications (App1 and App2) using Web API 2 and AngularJS.

App1 has a list of projects and App2 has a list of clients. They are both protected by the same ADFS.

Once I modify a project, I want to send a request from App1 (server-side) to App2. I think that it can be done by using Account Service (adfs). Can anyone recommend a solution?

Comment: Couple of options: 1. Expose a endpoint from App2 and call it from App1 once the project got updated. 2. Use messaging queues like kafka to publish and subscribe to messages.

Answer (score 0):

What version of ADFS?

Can you use web API?

ADFS 3.0 has support for web API only.

ADFS  4.0 has full OpenID Connect / OAuth support.